# How to get the int value form the linq

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

How can I resolve the issue below:

```
var xvalue = from cust in list 
             where cust.DisplayString == ((Data)x).CustomerName 
             select cust.Number;
int namX = xvalue;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query will always return a 'collection' of matching results, even if the collection returns just a single item.

If you know that your query will always match just a single item, you can use the Single Linq method:

```
var xvalue = from cust in list 
             where cust.DisplayString == ((Data)x).CustomerName 
             select cust.Number;
int namX = xvalue.Single();
```

Comment: Wouldn't `SingleOrDefault()` be safer?

Comment: You can't tell then, was there a number or not, because value types don't have "invalid" values. @Tim

Comment: @SargeBorsch - True, but how many tables are going to start the customer number at 0?

Comment: @Tim it depends on what it actually means. If this is just internal id, I would start from zero, for example.

Comment: @SargeBorsch - Without more context in the original question, it's hard to definitively say which way is better; however, in the absence of reasons to the contrary, I prefer to handle potential issues (like no data returned) in code rather than having exceptions raised (and/or caught).  `SingleOrDefault()` will handle the case of no match (though it too will error if there is more than one match).

Comment: @Tim Sometimes crash is better than erroneous results...
BTW, `Where` and `First[OrDefault]` can be replaced with just First[OrDefault], because it can do filtering itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
int namX = Convert.ToInt32(namx.FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

After returning a single item you should also get the property of the item which in this case is `Number`

```
var xvalue = from cust in list 
             where cust.DisplayString == ((Data)x).CustomerName 
             select cust.Number;

int namX = xvalue.Single().Number;
```

Comment: The Number property is already called in the select. Mean the enumerable contains only int or wathever Number return

Answer (score 0):

```
if u are sure that the condition "cust.DisplayString == ((Data)x).CustomerName" will return only one record than u can use code below this will return one number. other wise please see the next tip.

int namX = (from cust in list 
             where cust.DisplayString == ((Data)x).CustomerName 
             select cust).ToList().FirstOrDefault().Number;

if after applying the condition results can be more than one than surely it will be a list of int so the below code will work.


List<int> namX = (from cust in list 
             where cust.DisplayString == ((Data)x).CustomerName 
             select cust.Number).ToList();
```